# Repetition of string

Tags: ruby

User inputs three entries:

- First entry: Name
- Second entry: The nickname
- The third entry: The number of repetitions

Given the user input, I want to generate a text as follows. Given:

- Name: `"A"`
- The nickname: `"B"`
- Number of repetitions: `"3"`

the result should be:

```
"AB AB AB"
```

Comment: Hint: `"x" * y` gives you `"xx"` if `y` is 2. Same goes for `[ "x" ] * y` where you get `[ "x" ] * y` where you get `[ "x", "x" ]`. Pick which you need.

Comment: Try this: `name = gets.chomp; nickname=gets.chomp; repetitions=gets.to_i; (["#{name}#{nickname}"]*repetitions).join(' ')`.

Comment: No need to create a temp array, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025071/2767755) is a most direct solution.. @CarySwoveland :)

Comment: If you're desired result is the printing of a string on the terminal, say so; if the method is to return the string `"AB AB AB"`, include the quotes. In general, when asking questions ensure that all inputs and returned quantities are valid Ruby objects.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print 'Name: '
name = gets.chomp
print 'Nickname: '
nickname = gets.chomp
print 'Number: '
num = gets.to_i

result = ("#{name}#{nickname} " * num).strip
puts "Result is: #{result}"
```

Name: A
Nickname: B
Number: 3
Result is: AB AB AB

If you don't care about trailing space and just want to print result, you can simplify code by removing strip():

```
print 'Name: '
name = gets.chomp
print 'Nickname: '
nickname = gets.chomp
print 'Number: '
num = gets.to_i

result = "#{name}#{nickname} " * num
puts "Result is: #{result}"
```

Comment: Please disregard my earlier comment about `strip`. I suggest you roll-back to your original solution. I didn't mean that `strip` should be removed; I just have a hang-up about code that requires cleaning-up at the end (here the need for `strip`). Sorry for the inconvenience. I'll delete this comment when you've seen it. Perhaps remove your (now-orphaned) comment also (My friend, @Arup, please note the 'heng-up" bit.)

Answer (score 1):

```
name = 'A'
nickname = 'B'
rep = 3

(name + nickname) * rep                    # produces "ABABAB"
Array.new(rep, name + nickname).join(' ')  # produces "AB AB AB"
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the following one:

```rb
name = 'A'
nick = 'B'
rep = 3

arr = []
rep.times do |i|
  arr.push("#{name}#{nick}")
end

p arr # => ["AB", "AB", "AB"]
```

Explanation:

- `times` : iterates the given block int times, passing in values from zero to int - 1, from [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times)

Answer (score 0):

```
name = 'A'
nick = 'B'
rep = 3

namenick = "#{name}#{nick}"
"#{ namenick }#{ " #{namenick}"*(rep-1) }"
  #=> "AB AB AB"
```

Comment: strip version still good.. probably `rstrip` makes more sense.. :) That code reads like, copy `'AB '` 3 times, and then strip the trailing whitespace.